# No www Prefix Returns Django 404

Tags: python, django, dns, server, mezzanine

When I go to [www.keithirwin.us](http://www.keithirwin.us/), my site works fine.  But when I go to [keithirwin.us](http://keithirwin.us) without the prefix, I get a django 404 error ("Page not found at /").

Now since I get a django error and not my browser's "server not found" error, it must at least be pointing to my server.  But the django error says "You're seeing this page because debug = True" and that's false!  So who's django project is it?

This problem has really twisted my brain.  I'm just about ready to call an exorcist.

Comment: It's the same server, they have the same IP

Comment: Double check DEBUG in your settings.py file. Talk to your hosting provided - menkent.uberspace.de.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!  The DEBUG = True was from mezzanine's local_settings.py.  I still don't know why I'm getting a 404 but I can figure it out from here.